# How to select only direct children in list?

Tags: jquery

For example i have simple list

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And i am trying to get all `<li>` except those which is in second `<ul>`. Firstly i am tried `ul li`, then `ul > li` but still getting all `<li>`.

Comment: can you add a class/id to the topmost `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('ul:first').children('li')
```

I wouldn't recommend this, it will be better to add a id/class to the top ul and use it to select the children

```
<ul id="topul">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then

```
$('#topul').children('li')
```

Comment: Thanks, now I realized my mistake

Answer (score 1):

use `>` this as

```
jQuery( "parent > child" )
```

put a class on first ul as

```
<ul class ='ul-parent'>
```

and use class selector as follows

```
$('ul.ul-parent > li')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('li').not('ul ul li')
```

This will select only first level `li` elements.